# Setting `aiohttp.ClientSession` default params

Tags: python, python-requests, aiohttp

I'm migrating from `requests` to `aiohttp`, and I've previously used `requests.Session.params`, to set default query parameters for each request made with the session.

How do I properly achieve the equivalent with `aiohttp.ClientSession`?

I've tried:

- Subclassing `aiohttp.ClientSession` to overwrite the `_request` method.
  That raises a `DepcrecationWarning: Inheritance from ClientSession is discouraged`, though.
- Subclassing `aiohttp.ClientResponse` to overwrite the `__init__` method, and update the `params` there, and then passing the subclass to `aiohttp.ClientSession`.
  That won't work, since I need the custom parameters to be defined (and be mutable) on a session basis.

EDIT: Example of how I'd like my code to look, for clarification:

```
from aiohttp import ClientSession

session = ClientSession()
# Do something fancy here, or in the initialization of `ClientSession`, so that
# `default_params` is set as the default parameters for each request
default_params = dict(some_parameter="a value")

async with session.get("http://httpbin.org/get") as resp:
    j = await resp.json()
assert j["args"] == default_params

# Do something fancy here, where we change the default parameters
default_params.update(some_parameter="another value")

async with session.get("http://httpbin.org/get") as resp:
    j = await resp.json()
assert j["args"] == default_params
```

Answer (score 3):

> **Custom Request Headers**
>   If you need to add HTTP headers to a request, pass them in a dict to the headers parameter.

it's in the documentation http://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#custom-request-headers

```
url = 'http://example.com/image'
payload = b'GIF89a\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\x00,\x00\x00'
          b'\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x02\x00;'
headers = {'content-type': 'image/gif'}

await session.post(url,
                   data=payload,
                   headers=headers)
```

To add default & later a custom parameters, you can do it like this without doing any subclassing ([based on this part of documentation](http://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#passing-parameters-in-urls))

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession

async def fetch(url, params, loop):
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url, params=params) as response:
            print(response.request_info)
            print(str(response.url))
            print(response.status)
            args = await response.json()
            resp_text = await response.text()
            print('args:', args['args'])
            print(resp_text)

def main(url, params):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return loop.run_until_complete(fetch(url, params, loop))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'http://httpbin.org/get'
    default_params = {'param1': 1, 'param2': 2}
    main(url, default_params)
    new_params = {'some_parameter': 'a value', 'other_parameter': 'another value'}
    default_params.update(new_params)
    main(url, default_params)
```

Result:

```
RequestInfo(url=URL('http://httpbin.org/get?param1=1&param2=2'), method='GET', headers=<CIMultiDict('Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Host': 'httpbin.org', 'User-Agent': 'Python/3.5 aiohttp/3.4.4')>, real_url=URL('http://httpbin.org/get?param1=1&param2=2'))
  http://httpbin.org/get?param1=1&param2=2
  200
  args: {'param1': '1', 'param2': '2'}
  {
    "args": {
      "param1": "1", 
      "param2": "2"
    }, 
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "*/*", 
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
      "Connection": "close", 
      "Host": "httpbin.org", 
      "User-Agent": "Python/3.5 aiohttp/3.4.4"
    }, 
    "origin": "10.10.10.10", 
    "url": "http://httpbin.org/get?param1=1&param2=2"
  }

  RequestInfo(url=URL('http://httpbin.org/get?param1=1&param2=2&some_parameter=a+value&other_parameter=another+value'), method='GET', headers=<CIMultiDict('Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Host': 'httpbin.org', 'User-Agent': 'Python/3.5 aiohttp/3.4.4')>, real_url=URL('http://httpbin.org/get?param1=1&param2=2&some_parameter=a+value&other_parameter=another+value'))
  http://httpbin.org/get?param1=1&param2=2&some_parameter=a+value&other_parameter=another+value
  200
  args: {'other_parameter': 'another value', 'param1': '1', 'param2': '2', 'some_parameter': 'a value'}
  {
    "args": {
      "other_parameter": "another value", 
      "param1": "1", 
      "param2": "2", 
      "some_parameter": "a value"
    }, 
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "*/*", 
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
      "Connection": "close", 
      "Host": "httpbin.org", 
      "User-Agent": "Python/3.5 aiohttp/3.4.4"
    }, 
    "origin": "10.10.10.10", 
    "url": "http://httpbin.org/get?param1=1&param2=2&some_parameter=a+value&other_parameter=another+value"
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I need to set the parameters, not the headers. And I need to set them as defaults for the whole session, not just set in on a request basis. I've updated my question to include a clarifying example

Comment: @MadsMarquart hi, wait for a while, i'll edit the reply

Comment: Although this approach works in the case you're describing, it's really inefficient, and requires that I have a seperate function (in this case, called `main`), that recieves the URI. I need a `ClientSession` instance, that passes in the default parameters automatically every time `session.post` or `session.get` is called

Answer (score 2):

`ClientSession` accepts a `request_class` as one of its parameters. It is supposed to be an instance of `aiohttp.client_reqrep.ClientRequest`. You could inherit from that and set defaults but that is not very dynamic. Another option is to create a wrapper function that returns the `ClientRequest` and add your logic for the defaults there. Because `ClientSession` just calls `req = self._request_class(` [here](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/c5229adaebb972e7d9dba669073116e5ddf44178/aiohttp/client.py#L431)

Example 
Python 3.8

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp 
import aiohttp.client_reqrep

def wrap(default_params):
    def request_class(*args, **kwargs):
        """
        Merge defaults and pass them along to the ClientRequest class
        """
        kwargs["params"] = {**default_params, **params} \
            if (params := kwargs.get("params")) else default_params
        return aiohttp.client_reqrep.ClientRequest(*args, **kwargs)
    return request_class

async def run():
    default_params = dict(some_parameter="a value")
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(request_class=wrap(default_params)) as session:
        async with session.get("http://httpbin.org/get") as resp:
            j = await resp.json()
            print(j)            
        assert j["args"] == default_params

        # Do something fancy here, where we change the default parameters
        default_params.update(some_parameter="another value")

        async with session.get("http://httpbin.org/get") as resp:
            j = await resp.json()
            print(j)            
        assert j["args"] == default_params

        async with session.get("http://httpbin.org/get",
                               params={"foo": "bar"}) as resp:
            j = await resp.json()
            print(j)
        assert j["args"] == {**{"foo": "bar"}, **default_params}

        async with session.get("http://httpbin.org/get",
                               params={"some_parameter": "foo"}) as resp:
            j = await resp.json()
            print(j)
        assert j["args"] == {"some_parameter": "foo"}

# run
asyncio.run(run())
```